# How to apply Savitzky–Golay filter with backward window?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, finance, numerical-calculus

I would like to use Savitzky–Golay filter on stock price to calculate derivative order 1 and order 2. The fact is that standard Savitzky–Golay filter relies on a central window for filtering

So If I calculate Savitzky–Golay filter value on realtime data at day d I will need data for d-2, d-1, d, d+1, d+2. Of course I don't know d+1 and d+2 because they are in the futur. That's why I would need Savitzky–Golay filter using a backward window.

Do you know how I can calculate Savitzky–Golay filter for backward window ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Why would you want to use it on stock price data if it involves future points? Maybe you would instead want to use some other kiund of filter.

Comment: does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Treatment_of_first_and_last_points ?

Comment: I found this link that give coefficients for backward Savitsky-Golay : https://gregstanleyandassociates.com/whitepapers/FaultDiagnosis/Filtering/LeastSquares-Filter/leastsquares-filter.htm